# statistic with django

Tags: django, django-models

I am currently having the following

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  gender = models.BooleanField()

class Q(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class A(models.Model):
  q = models.ForeignKey(Q)
  profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
```

What I try to do is to query Q and get the number of Answers given by either male or female?

Unfortunately, I don't even have a better idea than writing custom SQL, which I'd rather avoid for the sake of database portability. How would I start?

Comment: Do you mean 'the number of answers for a particular Q grouped by male/female' or did you mean 'the total answers for all Qs grouped by male/female', or perhaps 'the number of answers for *each* Q grouped by male/female'?

Comment: what I am looking for is something like:

`question = Q.objects.get(pk=1)`
`males_answering = question.answers.filter(profile="gender.male").count()`
`print males_answering`

Answer (score 1):

You're there. You just need to actually use the right filter syntax. If you're trying filter on the `gender` field on `profile`, then you do that with `profile__gender`, so:

```
males_answering = question.answers.filter(profile__gender="male").count()
```